# How to print each sentence in a nested list without repeating the previous one

Tags: python

I'm having a problem with my code. I have a nested list which consist string of words that came from a sentence and each of this sentence are inside a list. Now my problem is how can I read each of these sentence one by one by not repeating the previous sentence.

```
with open('test','r') as f:
     test_iterate = test.read()

sample = [['This', 'is', 'a', 'sample','sentence'],['Sample','sentence','it','is']]

for words in test_iterate:
    print (words)
```

Now I don't know what to do. The output that I want:

```
This is a sample sentence
1
2
3
A
B
C

Sample sentence it is
1
2
3
A
B
C
```

Inside of test file:

```
1
2
3
A
B
C
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for words in sample:
    print(' '.join(words))
    for line in test_iterate:
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
for sentence in list_of_sentences:
    print(" ".join(sentence))
```

it iterates through you sentences stored as lists, and joins each element of the list (ie. words) with a space.